# how to connect Facebook, twitter, LinkedIn and gmail account in to a WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help on how to connect  Facebook, twitter, LinkedIn and gmail account  in to a WordPress site ?

Comment: Try searching the plugin repo

Comment: You also need help with asking a question. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

First: The simplest & fastest would be to search for the appropriate Wordpress Plugins, corresponding to each (our maybe a plugin that will handle all).

Second: Utilize the freely available API's for each service, and write your own. Note that this approach is strongly discouraged for beginners, or projects that have very little time to allow the coding for each of these.

Second (part 2): After which, you simply "connect" the code written using those API's to the Wordpress API methods which will create the associated local Wordpress account, which the Social login API's, pending a "success" response.

NOTE: NEVER store passwords in plain text, or by MD5 solely, read up on current MD5/salting Best Practices.

NOTE 2: As with ALL user input fields that access your database, "clean"the data first & use PHP PDO Prepared Statements to add the account info to the database to avoid SQL Injection attacks.